# mysqlslap - [error] while using INSERT query from cmd

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My Table structure is the following

```
========================================================================  
ID || USER_ID || USER_NAME || PUBLISH_DATE || UPDATED_BY || UPDATED_DATE  
(AI)---(int)-----(varchar)------(DATE)----------(int)--------(DATETIME)  

========================================================================
```

I am using this query for mysqlslap

```
INSERT INTO *TABLE_NAME* (USER_ID, USER_NAME, PUBLISH_DATE, UPDATED_BY, UPDATED_DATE) VALUES(123, 'my_name', 01-01-2018, 123,  NOW()).
```

and I get this error:

> Cannot run query INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (USER_ID, USER_NAME,
>   PUBLISH_DATE, PUBLISH_DATE, UPDATED_BY, UPDATED_DATE)
>   *ERROR* : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1.

Note that I am using MySQL Workbench 6.3 and MySQL database engine 5.7
OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using **mysqlslap** to execute query, a min difference can result error. Like here in my case it was "new line (enter)", which was included in query syntax in my .sql file. So my point (strictly)...

** The whole query should be in single flow, not separated by *new line (enter)*

Answer (score 2):

Try this: you missed single quote for date value '01-01-2018'

```
   INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (USER_ID, USER_NAME, PUBLISH_DATE, UPDATED_BY, 
   UPDATED_DATE) 
   VALUES(123, 'my_name', '01-01-2018', 123, NOW())
```

Comment: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysqlslap --user=root --password=something --create-schema=db_name --query=D:\mysqlslapquery\INSERT_QUERY.sql

Comment: I worked, but I think the problem was bit misdirected. Like when I changed '01-01-2018' to '2018-01-01'. It was all fine, query executed (single quote was help though)

Comment: it seems you have format problem of data - just use STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2018', '%d-%m-%Y') , it will solve your date format problem @CodeWorld and if it helped u please mark this as accepted